# Why is movement limited within enemies' borders outside the Great Wall?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Look at this screenshot
[image]

To the left you can see that the town Argos has the Great Wall, and quite far from it to the right I'm attacking Copenhagen. Both of these are controlled by Greece at the moment.

How come my soldiers, two musketmen and two longbowmen, only can move one tile within Copenhagen's borders? I know that the Great Wall often eclipses nearby territory belonging to other cities, but in this case it is clearly outside the wall. I also know that it can be a bit iffy with the graphics, so I reloaded the savegame and there's no wall nearby Copenhagen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/):

> - Enemy land units must expend 1 extra movement per tile inside your territory. The wall encompasses all of the territory of the civilization that has built it.
> - Free Walls in the city.

So the main thing to take from that is this section: **The wall encompasses all of the territory of the civilization that has built it**

And then within the trivia section:

> Although the wonder affects all tiles under the owner's control, what you see on the map only extends up to 5 tiles away from the city in which it is built with the exception of coast and ocean tiles, and offshore islands (though the tiles still have to be under your control), and it expands every time you reload the game until it reaches the 5 tile limit in all directions.

Answer (score 9):

The Great Wall graphic is purely ornamental. It's effect is civ-wide.

Comment: Really? Even if you have a city on another continent?

Comment: @Broman It's a game, it doesn't have to make sense :)

Comment: All other wonder and building graphics are ornamental too. There's nothing special about the tile junction where it plops down the Pyramids, for instance, or where your city's aqueduct leads. (Note that in Civ6, none of this is true - all of these things are crucially important!)